# disappearing reappearing php classes

Tags: php, git, apache, svn

I am using git to deploy a php application to an apache web server. After deploying, some files just revert to the last state randomly. If I added a new class file, the file disappears and I get a missing class error. Then it comes back. Someone else is having a simular issue where he deploys with SVN and his config class is gone until he reboots apache -Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix). Has anyone experienced a simular problem? The webserver is also using webmin

Comment: Is there any chance that you forgot to run `git add *` command to add new files ?

Comment: I tried that but the problem persist. Besides the problem comes and goes, its there for one page and then gone for 5 minutes, also the guy using SVN is having a related issue.